# Can't sync photos from DroidX2 external microSD card

Tags: memory, camera

I can't find or select the Camera Directory that is located on the microSD card in my Droid X2 phone from your Android App. It will only allow me to select the Camera Directory on the internal memory. However, all my photos are on the 16 GB microSD card. Any solutions to this issue? I am trying DropBox and it is working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the microSD card to your computer by using microSD adapter (instead of connecting your phone). You might be able to access all your files when connected directly to the computer.